# auto scroll for iframe does not work for me

Tags: javascript, html

I have this simple html page I wish it to scroll automatically to bottom the iframe however the codesimply does not work, it does not scroll down the iframe automatically,
anyone knows whats wrong with it?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showLog() {
    el = document.getElementById("log")
    el.innerHTML='<iframe id="myLogFrame" name="mylog" onload="this.contentWindow.document.documentElement.scrollTop=100" src="http://yahoo.com" width="100%" height="50%" align="middle" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0"></iframe>'
    el.scrollTop=el.scrollHeight
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="showLog()"/>
test1
<div id="log" style="width:100%">
```

</div></body></html>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, what you're trying to do is impossible due to the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) which restricts any and all access to documents that are not on your domain.

Your only chance is if the remote page has an anchor to the bottom of the page. If it does, you can link to that anchor. The browser will jump there.

```
<iframe src="http://yahoo.com#name_of_bottom_anchor">
```

Comment: I have replaced http://yahoo.com with mytestfile.txt which is a big test file and found locally on same folder as my test html and i access my test html with http://localhost:8080/statis/test.html and it still does not work, my iframe now looks like this:  el.innerHTML='<iframe id="myLogFrame" name="mylog" onload="this.contentWindow.document.documentElement.scrollTop=100" src="mytestfile.log.txt" width="100%" height="50%" align="middle" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0"></iframe>'

Comment: @Jason I don't think you can apply scrolling to a text file. Can you try with a HTML file first?

Comment: it didn't work for me even if i replace the mytestfile.log with mytestfile.html ... all I want is to scroll to bottom of log file which i'm printing, like tail... :/

Answer (score 0):

If your iframe is linked to another domain, web browser will blobk you access iframe's document, so you can access iframes scrollTop.